# Service variable not updating directive in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think this is a scoping problem, but I can't get my head around this.

I have a service as below:

```
(function (module) {

var portalService = function ($timeout, $http, $q, alerting, $cookies, $cookieStore, STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL, APP_COOKIE) {


    var _permissions = {};

    var permissions = function ()
    {
        var def = $q.defer();

        if (loggedIn) {

            if (_.size(_permissions) > 0) {
                def.resolve({ status: STATUS_OK }, _permissions);
            }
            else {
                $http({
                    url: "/Auth/GetPermissionsAsync",
                    method: "POST",
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data.result.status == STATUS_OK) {
                        _permissions = data.permissions;
                    }
                    def.resolve(data.result, data.permissions);

                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    def.reject("Failed to retrieve permissions.", status);
                });
            }


        }
        else {
            def.resolve({ status: STATUS_OK }, _permissions);
        }
        return def.promise;

    }



    var logOn = function (email, password) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: "/Auth/LogInAsync",
                method: "POST",
                data: { email: email,
                        password: password},
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //testing if we can even update this...
                _permissions=[{parent: "Administer", items: [{name: "Users", route: "dashboard"}]}];
                def.resolve(data.result);

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    def.reject("Failed to contact the server to log in.",status);
            });
            return def.promise;
    };

    var register = function (data) {
        var def = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: "/Auth/RegisterAsync",
            method: "POST",
            data: data
            ,
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                def.resolve(data.result);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            def.reject("Registration failed to contact the server",status);
        });
        return def.promise;
    };

    var logOut = function (data) {
        var def = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: "/Auth/SignOutAsync",
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            _permissions = {};
            def.resolve(data.result);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            def.reject("Signing out failed to contact the server.", status);
        });
        return def.promise;
    };

    var loggedIn = function ()
    {
        if ($cookies.get(APP_COOKIE))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    var currentPermissions = function ()
    {
        return _permissions;
    }


    return {
        logOn: logOn,
        register: register,
        logOut: logOut,
        loggedIn: loggedIn,
        permissions: permissions,
        currentPermissions : _permissions
    };

};

module.factory("portalService", portalService);

}(angular.module("clportal")));
```

I have a directive as below:

```
    (function (module) {

    var navMenu = function (portalService) {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            templateUrl: "/Template/NavMenu",
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                scope.permissions = portalService.currentPermissions;
            }
        };
    };

    module.directive("navmenu", navMenu);

}(angular.module("clportal")));
```

And, I have the inclusions as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="clportal">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out/css/anim-in-out.css" />
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Static navbar -->

        <div ng-controller="navController">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Customer Center</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">
                    <navmenu></navmenu>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div growl inline="true" reference="global"></div>
        <div class="row" >
            <route-loading-indicator></route-loading-indicator>
            <div ng-if="!isRouteLoading" ui-view="" class="col-lg-12 anim-in-out anim-fade" data-anim-speed="1000" ></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out/anim-in-out.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/app-clportal.js"> </script>
    
    <script src="~/lib/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/services/exceptionHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/services/portalService.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/js/app/services/alerting.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/directives/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/directives/compareDirective.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/js/app/directives/formInput.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/controllers/homeController.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/js/app/controllers/loginController.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/js/app/controllers/registerController.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/js/app/directives/loadingView.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/controllers/dashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/controllers/navController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/directives/navMenu.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Now when I call the logOn method, via the portalService, in theory it should set the _permissions local variable, which then should update the appropriate directive navMenu so  that it sees the new menu option, and renders appropriately.  However this does not work.  I can use simple examples and its fine, but there is something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm doing it, scoping wise I would assume and I can't see it.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ajax requests are asynchronous.   The function has already returned before the Ajax request is finished.  You need to carry the async flow with a callback or promise, or somehow make it synchronous.

Comment: Err, that had nothing to do with it :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a simple bug - LogOff was being called before log on, and that was setting the local variable to an empty object - this basically cut off the reference that was stored against the directive.

So I needed to set the size to zero on the array if i wanted to clear it out, to make sure that the original reference wasn't lost, and use push to push new values to the array.  Working fine now.